# Testing a Node JS application that uses SQL connection pools and commits

Tags: sql, node.js, testing, connection

I am writing a test suite using Mocha & Chai for a Node JS application that implements MariaDB & Oracle SQL connection pools and commits, and am not seeing how to create transactions and rollbacks *on top of that* for the tests.

The application creates and terminates a pooled connection for each and every SQL request.  From what I have read, if I want to have a transaction and rollback, it has to be over the same connection as the SQL request.  Because the application creates a new pooled connection after the test already starts, I am not seeing how to encapsulate this in a transaction and rollback for the test.

Additionally, I understand that a commit is a permanent, non reversible action.  So, if the application has commits, how can I run a transaction and rollback on top of that for the test?

Pooled connections and commits are fundamental aspects of SQL and I (naively?) expect that these have to be able to be tested using common tools and practices, but I am finding *nothing* on the Internet that speaks to them in a manner consistent with the application I am testing.  I know that I can rewrite the application to accommodate the tests, but that seems like a fundamental code crime.

Can anyone point me to material that shows how to create tests for applications that use connection pools and commits without rewriting the application?

Comment: Without knowing the application, it would be hard to give a solution that doesn't need a rewrite!  Speaking for Oracle here: If your application creates a connection, then presumably you are executing a DML (e..g INSERT or UPDATE) statement immediately after. This begins a transaction.  Then the app has to call rollback on that connection.  If you don't use autocommit, then when the connection is released back to the pool, it will rollback automatically.  If you are testing, then do you really need to rollback?  Do you have a test database or schema that you can create & destroy for testing?

Comment: Hello Christopher - thank you very much for taking the time to help me on this. I have a test database and tables can be created and destroyed at will. From what I have seen in the code, the application executes a COMMIT after every INSERT / UPDATE command.  Currently, the only way I can think to roll back after each test (because each INSERT / UPDATE is accompanied with a COMMIT) is to manually re-create the tables, which I was hoping to avoid.